# Download link will download the file in system download path

Tags: filestream, fileinputstream, fileinfo

Error Code with fileinnfo

```
FileInfo File = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("/Content/ExcelFiles/SalesTarget.xlsx"));

        if (File != null)
        {
            int Size = Convert.ToInt32(File.Length);

            string FileName = File.FullName;
            int Position = FileName.LastIndexOf("\\");
            FileName = FileName.Substring(Position + 1);
             string test = File.GetType().ToString();
            string filepath = Server.MapPath("/Content/ExcelFiles/SalesTarget.xlsx");
            string ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(Server.MapPath("/Content/ExcelFiles/SalesTarget.xlsx"));
            byte[] FileData = new byte[Size];
            char[] chars = Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(FileData);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filepath);
            reader.Read(chars, 0, Size);     // Throwing error here
            Response.ContentType = ContentType;
            StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();

            SB.Append("filename=");
            SB.Append(FileName);

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", SB.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(FileData);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            //File..Read(FileData, 0, Size);
        }
```

Running Code with Httppostedfile Class:

```
 HttpPostedFileBase File = Request.Files["FileToLoad"];

        if (File != null)
        {
            int Size = File.ContentLength;

            if (Size <= 0)
            {
                ViewData["ERROR"] = "You uploaded an empty file,please browse a valid file to upload";
                return View("../Shared/Error");
            }

            string FileName = File.FileName;
            int Position = FileName.LastIndexOf("\\");
            FileName = FileName.Substring(Position + 1);
            string ContentType = File.ContentType;
            byte[] FileData = new byte[Size];
            File.InputStream.Read(FileData, 0, Size);

            theModel.AddAFile(FileName, Size, ContentType, FileData);
        }
```

I want to download existing file from directory instead of using httppostedfile, so I am getting error while reading file data.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: @leppie error is : Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.

Comment: and its coming on this line of above code reader.Read(chars, 0, Size);   // Throwing error here

Comment: I dont understand the code, it is not doing anything useful. Also, you should use `chars.Length` instead of `Size`.

Comment: Response.BinaryWrite(FileData); and here i have to write chars ??? but how it will work?

Comment: hey @leppie just i want that on click of download button the excel file from directory with some data,should be download to the system Download Folder